# Fuse Install All Dependencies on Bundle install - Installing Kafka on Fuse

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, osgi-bundle, fuseesb

Is there a way to install all required dependencies of a bundle on fuse?  I am trying to install kafka module using the following command:

```
 install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka_2.10/0.8.1.1_1
```

The bundle installs successfully, however none of its dependencies are installed.  Kafka service mix bundle has following dependency requirements:

```
<servicemix.osgi.import.pkg>
com.yammer.metrics*;version="[2.2,3)", javax.management*, joptsimple;version="[3.2,4)";resolution:=optional, org.I0Itec.zkclient*;resolution:=optional, org.apache.log4j*;resolution:=optional, org.apache.zookeeper*;version="[3.3,4)", org.xerial.snappy;resolution:=optional, scala*;version="[2,3)", sun.misc;resolution:=optional, sun.nio.ch;resolution:=optional
</servicemix.osgi.import.pkg>
```

Each of these required packages have their own dependencies further.  Installing all of these going to be a error prone and painful process.  Is there a command line option or a fuse plugin which can take care of this problem?